# Should there be any need to type 'static' before each member in a static class?

Tags: c#, static

Since a `static` class can contain only `static` members, should there be any need to type `static` before each member?

What I really want to know is that: can a `static` class contain anything other than `static` members? If not, the compiler should help to append `static` to all members of a `static` class rather than complain that ...

Comment: doesn't your last sentence (last 3 words) answer your own question?

Comment: Doesn't the documentation for the `static` keyword answer your question?

Comment: Also, note that the title of your question is very different than what is asked in the text -- and the title is also clearly off-topic for the site, as "should X be the default?" is opinion-based.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about speculative information about what a language syntax could have been regardless of what it is.

Comment: Good question. I guess its not needed as it can be inferred from the class header. Maybe its just to stick to naming guidelines and is easier to read.

Comment: @Jon and peter-ritchie I thought so but I don't know where to post it. Any suggestion?

Comment: @afaolek: Perhaps ask in the C# chatroom?

Comment: Ok, I'll do that, although @dcastro seems to have given a satisfying answer. I'll try that chat room for more opinions. Thanks Jon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since a static class can contain only static members, should there be any need to type static before each member?

There is no *need*, per se, but it makes your code much more readable.

The same argument could be made for interface implementations - since they *have* to be public, why do we need to explicitly mark them as public?

Imagine a world where you don't have to mark interface implementations as public:

```
public interface I
{
    void M();
}

public class C : I
{
    void M();

    void M2();
}
```

Methods `M` and `M2` seem to have the same level of access. However, `M` is public, and `M2` is private. By having the compiler force you to mark `M` as public, the issue goes away.

**Readability** and **consistency** are the reasons why you're forced to mark interface implementations as public and members of a static class as static: public members are *always* marked as public and static members are *always* marked as static.

Comment: So why not enforcing the use of `public` keyword in the method definition of an interface? Isn't it similar to enforcing the use of `static` keyword in a static class?

Comment: @LucaCremonesi That's a very good point. I would argue that, because interface *declarations* tend to be small (let's say, 10~50 lines), and because none of its members have a body, it's hard to forget that the method you're looking at belongs to an interface and is therefore public. I'd say it's very hard to mistake an interface declaration (whose members are always public) for a class implementation (whose members are private by default). Since there's less risk of confusion, the language designers probably decided to waive the restriction. But that's simply my opinion.

Comment: (The fact that IDEs like Visual Studio also color the interfaces with yellow, and the fact that it's conventional for interface names to begin with `I`, also makes it harder to mistake an interface for a class.)